# Why does Google Safe Browsing remove its URL? then some of them gets re-added but why?

Tags: url, phishing, safe-browsing, safe-browsing-api

Why does Google Safe Browsing remove its URL? then some of them gets re-added but why?
I know there will be some false positives collected in the first place, but if I use the python library ([https://github.com/afilipovich/gglsbl](https://stackoverflow.com)) to sync local database of safe browsing, I see that a lot of URLs are being removed daily.
Is it possible that it is just removing in local database so that safe browsing keeps local database size small?
Or is it really that large number of URLs get removed from the list daily? then why? can I say those are all false positives? then why do some of them reappear later on?

I downloaded local database of safe browsing to see added and removed URls.
I checked removed URLs with VirusTotal to see if there is any changes in scanned result.